# Using clipboard on Uno Platform

Tags: c#, android, uwp, clipboard, uno-platform

I am trying to get content from the clipboard on Android with:

```
DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();
```

The namespace and the method exists both on uwp and android. But in the latter, there is an not implemented exception, when running the code.

To my knowledge, the clipboard should be implemented in uno platform. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Clipboard.GetContent` is [implemented in Uno 3.0](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/da24c1700a1da1aeed088e355581d850cb914a33/src/Uno.UWP/ApplicationModel/DataTransfer/Clipboard.Android.cs#L71) (still in development as of 2020/07/26), and you can use [it as follows](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/da24c1700a1da1aeed088e355581d850cb914a33/src/SamplesApp/UITests.Shared/Windows_ApplicationModel/ClipboardTests.xaml.cs#L107):

```cs
private async void Paste()
{
   var content = Clipboard.GetContent();
   Text = await content.GetTextAsync();
}
```